# Why is sbt-scapegoat trying to resolve version 1.0.0?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt-scapegoat by adding this to plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.0.4")
```

Then in by build.scala file I'm doing this:

```
import com.sksamuel.scapegoat.sbt.ScapegoatSbtPlugin.autoImport._
scapegoatVersion            := "1.1.0"
```

This is what's shown on the sbt-scapegoat github site.  I fire up sbt and let it resolve sbt-scapegoat 1.0.4, which it does.  So far so good.  Then if I run scapegoat I get:

```
[info] Resolving com.sksamuel.scapegoat#scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10;1.0.0 ...
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10/1.0.0/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: com.sksamuel.scapegoat#scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10;1.0.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/wmy965/.ivy2/local/com.sksamuel.scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10/1.0.0/scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.sksamuel.scapegoat#scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.10;1.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Where is 1.0.0 dependency coming from?  My project is scala 2.11.7 and I'm using sbt 0.13.11.  I don't see any mention of another resolver on the sbt-scapegoat web site.

In my output, my console shows a bunch of found analysis errors but the generated HTML doc is basically empty--doesn't show the errors displayed on the console.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's also looking for scapegoat for 2.10, which doesn't exist. Some questions: 1. Do you have a multiproject build? 2. Are the paths to files you mention `project/plugins.sbt` and `project/build.scala`? 3. What do you get from `show scapegoatVersion` command?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's mutliproject.  2. Project paths are as you specified. 3. Output here: (sorry for formatting) [info] dotdash_messages/*:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.2.1
[info] dotdash/*:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.2.1
[info] root/*:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.0.0

Comment: I should add that when I tried to add scapegoatVersion := "1.2.1" to root it got a different failed dependency because root is compiling with scala 2.10 (sbt) and the non-root modules in 2.11.  Not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `scapegoatVersion` for subprojects, you need to either put it in common settings as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html), or use `scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild := "1.1.0"`. To avoid the error, I think setting `scalaVersion` in the root project would work:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(dotdash, dotdash_messages).
  settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
  )
```

or again use `scalaVersion in ThisBuild`.

I also suggest raising an issue at https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer from Alexey, Just to answer *WHERE*, you may want to check [ScapegoatPlugin.scala](https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/sbt/ScapegoatSbtPlugin.scala).
This is an sbt [Auto Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Plugins.html) and the method buildSettings have overridden the scapegoatVersion to be used.

```
override def buildSettings = super.buildSettings ++ Seq(
          scapegoatVersion := "1.0.0",
          scapegoatRunAlways := true,
          scapegoatConsoleOutput := true,
          scapegoatVerbose := true,...
```

We can specify the version we choose to use, `scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild`.

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing from above works, so potentially there are two problems and mine has been resolved by using [fixed version of plugin](https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat/issues/63)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.0.9")
```